# Sprintf showing few arguments

Tags: r

I am using sprintf function to replace the texts in a string. But it is throwing an error. I know I am passing as vector. But is there a way to get expected output

```
sprintf("This is the link % s  also there is another link, % s This is the link % s ",
        '<a href=https://google.com>s</a>', 
        '<a href=https://yahoo.com>s</a>', 
        '<a href=https://google.com>s</a>')

### Expected output
[1] "This is the link <a href=https://google.com>s</a>  also there is another link, <a href=https://yahoo.com>s</a> This is the link <a href=https://google.com>s</a> "
```

When I replace above operation with below code

```
split_links <- c("<a href=https://google.com>s</a>", "<a href=https://yahoo.com>s</a>" , "<a href=https://google.com>s</a>")

sprintf("This is the link % s  also there is another link, % s This is the link % s ",split_links)
Error in sprintf("This is the link % s  also there is another link, % s This is the link % s ",  : 
  too few arguments
```

I am getting above error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert to a `list` and use `do.call`

```
do.call(sprintf, c(fmt = "This is the link % s  also there is another link, % s This is the link % s ", as.list(split_links)))
```

-output

```
[1] "This is the link <a href=https://google.com>s</a>  also there is another link, <a href=https://yahoo.com>s</a> This is the link <a href=https://google.com>s</a> "
```

Answer (score 0):

The string in `sprintf` requires 3 separate arguments whereas you are passing all the arguments as one vector in `sprintf`. You can pass each individual arguments separately to `sprintf`.

```
split_links <- c("<a href=https://google.com>s</a>", "<a href=https://yahoo.com>s</a>" , "<a href=https://google.com>s</a>")

sprintf("This is the link % s  also there is another link, % s This is the link % s ",split_links[1], split_links[2], split_links[3])

#[1] "This is the link <a href=https://google.com>s</a>  also there is another link, <a href=https://yahoo.com>s</a> This is the link <a href=https://google.com>s</a> "
```

If `length` of `split_links` is bigger and you want to avoid typing each argument separately use `do.call` method as already suggested.